# Zend Php Foreach Loop array

Tags: php, zend-framework, loops, foreach

I have a input field and a array of email from DB table.

I am comparing the similarity of the input field to the array.

But some how, I am stuck with the loop.

Does that loop check compare each email with the input field?

It always bring me to google.com no matter what i input same or not

Here's the code from the controller:

```
if (isset($_POST['btn_free_download']))
                {
                    // Get current input email from input field
                    $email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email');
                    // Get all emails from the user
                    $referred_users = $this->_helper->user()->getReferredUsers()->toArray();
                    // Check the similarity which it with a loop
                    foreach ($referred_users as $referred_user)
                    {
                       similar_text($email, $referred_user['email'], $similar);
                    }
                    // If yes, Pop up message or redirect to some page
                    if ($similar < 97)
                    {
                        $this->_redirect('http://google.com');
                    }
                    // If not, redirect user to free download page
                    else 
                    {
                        $this->_redirect('http://yahoo.com');
                    }
 }
```

Comment: You have declared $referred_users but then you initiate your loop with $this->referred_users. This should be the same variable.

Comment: What does function similar_text do?  What is $similar initially?

Comment: @Dylan http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php check the manual, $similar is the percent of the similar text which is passed as a reference as third argument, similar_text() will calculate the similarity in percent for you.

Comment: @roko oh wow, I thought it was a custom function.  TIL.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) . Foreach function is same wether you use it on zend or any other framework or raw php only.

```
$referred_users = $this->_helper->user()->getReferredUsers()->toArray();
```

> $referred_users will probably hold an array of emails from the table
>   user, say:

```
$referred_users = array("one@email.com", "two@email.com", "three@email.com")
```

> then when you use foreach loop it will iterate through each of the
>   emails in the array

```
foreach ($referred_users as $referred_user)
{
   // for the first loop $referred_user = one@email.com, for second time $referred_user = two@email.com and goes on
    similar_text($email, $referred_user['email'], $similar);
}
```

> Now let us discuss your logic here:

```
                   // If yes, Pop up message or redirect to some page
                    if ($similar < 97)
                    {
                        $this->_redirect('http://google.com');
                    }
                    // If not, redirect user to free download page
                    else 
                    {
                        $this->_redirect('http://yahoo.com');
                    }
```

Until and unless the last element in the array $referred_users is exactly equal to your $email

```
i.e. $email = "three@email.com"
```

you will always be given result for $similar less than 97% which means you will be redirected to google.

Which I assume you are not trying to do and probably not familiar with foreach function which is why you are not getting the expected result.

Assuming you are trying to do something like, check for the emails in the array if any of the email in the array matches (if array is from table check if the email entered from param is equal to any of the emails in the table) then redirect to somewhere or show some message else carry on. Solution below might be helpful to you.

```
   $similarText = false;
   foreach ($referred_users as $referred_user)
   {
       // for the first loop $referred_user = one@email.com, for second time $referred_user = two@email.com and goes on
        similar_text($email, $referred_user['email'], $similar);
        if ($similar > 97) {
            $similarText = true;
            break;
        }
    }


                   // If yes, Pop up message or redirect to some page
                    if ($similarText)
                    {
                        $this->_redirect('http://google.com');
                    }
                    // If not, redirect user to free download page
                    else 
                    {
                        $this->_redirect('http://yahoo.com');
                    }
```

Hope you got the idea. But please do check the manual before posting a question in the future.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a try like what you said and see if it works or not. And sorry about the late reply...

Comment: And yea is what I want, check if any emails match in the array if one of the first one match in the array it will exit.

Comment: Thanks you, it works I didn't know putting a break in a loop will exit the loop. I learn something